# Do AmE and BrE dictionaries treat compound adjectives differently?

Tags: american-english, british-english, dictionaries, compound-adjectives

My (BrE) OED and (AmE) dictionary.com **both** list the adjective 'middle-class' **with a hyphen**.
The OED provides these examples:

> a middle-class attitude
>   The magazine is very **middle-class**.

The (AmE) CMOS provides these examples:

> a middle-class neighborhood
>   the neighborhood is **middle class**

OED lists the adjective 'up to date' with **no hyphens** and provides these examples:

> This technology is bang **up to date**.
>   up-to-date clothes

dictionary.com lists the adjective 'up-to-date' **with hyphens** CMOS and provides these examples:

> His equipment was **up to date**
>   an up-to-date solution

It appears the principle of hyphenating compound adjectives before nouns is treated differently by dictionaries using BrE and AmE. It appears:

- BrE dictionaries may list compound adjectives as hyphenated or not; they assume writers will always hyphenate them before nouns, **but**
- AmE dictionaries always compound adjectives as hyphenated; they assume writers will NOT hyphenate them after nouns.

I hope someone has a satisfactory explanation. I fear I'm about to have a nervous breakdown. :(

Comment: I think this needs more examples to really validate the pattern you're inferring. (i.e. I'm not yet convinced that this is a real pattern)

Comment: FAIR ENOUGH! ... I will work on that ... But you see the pattern that bothers me! ... HALLELUJAH!   I have looked for other examples but the online Merriam-Webster Dictionary does not give many sample sentences. Do you know of an online American English dictionary that does list a significant number of examples? For my purposes, I need examples after nouns.

Comment: This is not the actual OED. This is the *Oxford Learners Dictionary*. And I suspect the reason they only have hyphenated examples is that they only considered hyphenated examples, because they're defining a hyphenated word. The actual OED (only available through libraries, universities, subscriptions, etc.) has non-hyphenated examples, such as *"The tests were geared to white middle class society."*

Comment: @PeterShor. It is no Mickey Mouse dictionary. It has almost 2,000 densely packed pages. It has only about two-thirds of the number of definitions as the OED and perhaps some are shorter. It has some additional features designed to help to those learning English as a second language. I would be ASTONISHED if it defined ANYTHING shown differently in both.

Comment: That's very confusing, then. Online, the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/middle-class_2) has the example *"The magazine is very middle-class."* The online OED, which I can access through my university, does not have this example under *"middle class"*.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt whether this is anything to do with American of British usage, and I think you question is based on false premises which I shall deal with as an appendix. My doubt is supported (as far as this is indicative) by a [Google ngram analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=middle+class+attitude%2Cmiddle-class+attitude&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1890&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmiddle%20class%20attitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiddle%20-%20class%20attitude%3B%2Cc0) of the use of the alternatives ‘middle class attitude’ and ‘middle class-attitude’ in British and US books:

[image: British v. US use of middle-class]

Of course, there may be differences in writing in journalism or specialized technical publications, but this does not lead one to believe there is any tradition of different usage.

The  [examples](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/middle_class) in Oxford Dictionaries online (not the OED) provide illustrations using what is recognized as standard good style to avoid what Fowler called [‘false scent’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_scent).

Consider the alternatives in the first example:

> (1) a middle class attitude
>
> (2) a middle-class attitude

If I read (1) the noun ‘middle’ follows the article ‘a’, so for a moment I think the phrase refers to that. However it actually refers to ‘attitude’ and middle is used as part of a compound adjective. I have taken ‘false scent’ and have to readjust. If I read (2) the hyphen prevents this as I read ‘middle’ along with ‘class’. The writer has helped me read his work — regardless of my nationality — to the benefit of both of us.

Now take an example of the predicative use of the adjective (below). Here the noun ‘attitude’ precedes the compound adjective, so there is little chance of ‘false scent’ and the hyphen may be omitted.

> His attitude is so middle class.

**Addendum: False Premises in the Question**

My answer attempts to address those parts of the question which I think are answerable and on-topic here, and avoids accepting the following, what I consider, false premises:

1. *That the sources quoted are dictionaries in the historical sense of the word.* Printed dictionaries generally define words, provide spellings and perhaps plurals. The full OED provides examples of first usages. These on-line resources provide modern examples of usage, either invented or selected to reflect the editorial style of the site. Printed dictionaries generally do not do this.  Comparing two such on-line resources and attributing their differences to one characteristic (nationality) whithout further evidence is really unsupportable.
2. *Dictionary.com only uses US dictionaries.* According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary.com),  “The content for Dictionary.com is based on the Random House Unabridged Dictionary, with other content from the Collins English Dictionary, American Heritage Dictionary and others.”
3. *US writers consult dictionary.com, whereas British writers consult Oxford Dictionaries online.* I would suggest most people use what Google throws at them.
4. *Professional writers consult on-line dictionaries to find out how to hyphenate words.* I would suggest that most use whatever style they have used for years. As a scientist in an area where there is a vast potential for clumsy compound nounal adjectives I learned from criticism from my mentors or editorial reviewers. I have published in British and American scientific journals and found no difference in this respect.

Comment: @sumelic. Thanks. I have decided to ask two new questions, one for those who use British English, the other for American English. There DEFINITELY is a difference between how the OED and M-WD treat compound adjectives AFTER nouns.

Comment: @sumelic — Then Ross will presumably not accept my answer. That is how SE works. (He may even vote it down or have voted it down). But I deliberately did not answer the question as he wanted because it is based on false premises. I will modify my answer to clarify.

Comment: Who says: `3. British writers consult dictionary.com, whereas US writers consult Oxford Dictionaries`? Not the OP. And you should give evidence of *invented* examples of modern usage added to online dictionaries. This might be true, but I feel that is your personal viewpoint, not something based on real-life observation.

Comment: So that the OP does not suffer from a nervous breakdown, perhaps you should clearly state your nationality. English, Scottish, Welsh or just plain British?

Comment: @David. False premises be damned. PLEASE READ the examples sentences at the top of the OP.
BOTH The Oxford and Merriam-Webster dictionaries define “middle-class” with a hyphen.  
The OED provides this example:
The magazine is very middle-class. 
CMOS uses the M-WD. It provides this example sentence BECAUSE that is what the M-WD would recommend:  
the neighborhood is middle class.  
I WILL be satisfied and happy as soon as anyone can explain why the TRANSLATION from the dictionaries' definitions to their examples are different.

Comment: @David. One thing that would be very useful is knowing how to use ngrams to list the frequency of 'middle-class' and 'middle-class' IN THE PREDICATE POSITION! I cannot figure out a way of separating out those from uses before a noun. I assume results for the latter - which all of us here understand fully - would be swamping those cases that do interest me in the two analyses you provided.

Comment: Google Ngrams is good tests for some things, but for others it is a fallacious source of information: This especially includes punctuation. Perhaps even more-so than the dictionaries:  [In the past, they had some problems with detecting hyphenation,](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2469/124936) and perhaps they still do.  Would you please perform and provide us with an assessment of your ngrams' accuracy?

Comment: @Tonepoet. It appears great minds do think alike :) As far as I know, past problems ngrams had with hyphens have been resolved. I would be very interested in its results if I could find some way of limiting an analysis to uses AFTER a noun.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — Sorry. Thinking faster than I'm typing (or vice versa). Have correct that.

Comment: @Tonepoet — I performed some manual checks of the books listed and the instances to confirm that the hyphenation was being handled properly and to confirm the national origin of the books. You can do that too. Until demonstrated otherwise those data imply similar US and British usage for hyphenation of that phrase in books over a long period of time.

Comment: @RossMurray — Tut, tut. Strong language. May I suggest that you do some research of your own with ngram or printed dictionaries, rather than suggesting that thought experiments prove genius. Shades of crying "fake news".

Comment: @David. I have already purchased the best print dictionary available in the city I live in, Jogjakarta in central Java, Indonesia. I would have done so already if I knew how to get ngrams to produce results I thought were relevant. I have read the documentation but I'm no expert. I have repeatedly said here I am only interested in what to do with compound adjectives after nouns, so suggesting I'd be interested in ngrams results for just those is not an attempt to prove anything.

Comment: Down below where everything has since been deleted someone suggested I had asked something that was **UNANSWERABLE** (their font choice). I have an update for them. The relevant and complete answers were, in fact, (1) Yes, and (2) Yes.

Comment: @RossMurray — If the "relevant and complete answer" to a question is "Yes" or "No" neither question nor answer is suitable for SE EL&U, as the [Help section](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) of this site makes abundantly clear. That is why questions get put on hold and answers get deleted. Something to bear in mind when next posting. It can save a lot of aggravation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your focus on those hyphens in dictionaries may have over-specialised your question a bit.

I assumed that the use of a hyphen *after* the noun would simply depend on whether the compound adjective is treated as an established expression, and a quick search led indeed to [grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp):

> Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.
>
> Examples:
>   an off-campus apartment
>   state-of-the-art design
>
> When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen is usually not necessary.
>
> Example: The apartment is off campus.
>
> However, **some established compound adjectives are always hyphenated.** Double-check with a dictionary or online.
>
> Example: The design is state-of-the-art.

Now, as is so often the case with spelling, that last bit doesn't actually help anyone to figure out how to spell a compound adjective. It merely explains *why* some of them take a hyphen.

So, going by your examples, it seems that the OED simply regards *middle-class* as an *established* compound adjective, or a set expression, whereas CMOS does not.

The real problem here is that deciding on how "established" an expression is, is a very subjective process, and without any actual, definitive, prescriptive authority on the English language, you will simply have to choose your own sources (i.e. dictionaries) if you want to back up your decision to use a hyphen in a compound adjective or not.

And yes, in general you will find differences between dictionaries roughly following the lines of different English dialects, but in some cases, as your *middle(-)class* example shows, even two dictionaries following the same dialect may disagree on the finer points of a compound adjective's being *established*.